# Laravel Nova | How can i pass default value while storing Boolean field from Laravel nova resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I have one field in a database table and its default value is true 
now when someone creates an entry from Laravel nova that time I want to pass true by default without showing that field in creating and update form... so can anyone help me how can I solve this.

```
Boolean::make('Is Active', 'is_active')->onlyOnIndex(),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default value on your model and nova should automaticly pick it up.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#default-attribute-values

```
protected $attributes = [
    'is_active' => true,
];
```

Comment: hey robbin I already set default value in database level but here when someone store or create a record from Laravel nova that time I just want to set a default value to true.

Comment: and i am using that field so many places in normal laravel project but only in nova i want to pass default value

Comment: Is this maybe something you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389551/laravel-nova-resource-extending-overriding-the-create-method

Comment: as I see there is no way to do so your answer will be helpful to achieve my task thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
    Boolean::make('Active','active')
        ->trueValue('1')
        ->falseValue('0')
        ->withMeta(['value' => $this->active ?? true]),
```

On create the value of the active column will be null/empty as it is a new "item" and knows nothing of the DB default value This will set the form active field to true. On update it will use the DB value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this will not work as $this->active will always be false if it's not checked ....